# Join tables with different amount of rows using SQL in QGIS3

Tags: qgis, sql, attribute-joins, table

I want to join two tables. The second table has only one row. I want to append this row to every row of table 1. How can I achieve that with SQL in QGIS3?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a "Virtual Layer" (Layer Menu > Create Layer > New Virtual Layer...) and use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
```

Then you can export as another format.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use "Vector general > Execute SQL" tool.

Select "No geometry", specify a file path and use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
```

[image]

Result:

[image]